# How to check the color of a button in UITest

Tags: android, xamarin, uitest

I'm writing a test using Xamarin.UITest and I want to examine the coloor of a specific UI button. From the Repl I can grab the button like this:

```
>>> app.Query(c => c.Button()).First()
Query for Button() gave 1 results.
{
    Id => "buttonGo",
    Description => "android.widget.Button{b312e568 VFED..C. ........ 26,234-454,314 #7f060033 app:id/buttonGo}",
    Rect => {
        Width => 428,
        Height => 80,
        X => 26,
        Y => 328,
        CenterX => 240,
        CenterY => 368
    },
    Label => null,
    Text => "Go!",
    Class => "android.widget.Button",
    Enabled => true
}
```

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any property that will give me the colour. Is there a way for me to pull more info from the button or another way to query that I could use to find the button color?

---

Update: So I'm making some progress, thanks to the recommendation to use Invoke. I'm now trying to do the following:

```
>>> app.Query(c => c.Button("buttonGo").Invoke("getBackground"))
```

Which should call [getBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getBackground) and return me a background drawable but instead throws the following error:

```
Ignoring failed json serialisation of result of Query for Button("buttonGo").Invoke("getBackground"). Value was never requested
Query for Button("buttonGo").Invoke("getBackground") gave no results.
null
```

If I call getHeight everything works as expected so I'm a bit baffled here:

```
>>> app.Query(c => c.Button("buttonGo").Invoke("getHeight"))
Query for Button("buttonGo").Invoke("getHeight") gave 1 results.
[
    [0] 80
]
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is `AppQuery.Invoke`
See Xamarin.UITest documentation "[Invoke a Method on an AppResult or UI Element](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/cheatsheet/#Invoke_a_Method_on_an_AppResult_or_UI_Element)"

Update:

I think you can't return complex types, but you can chain the `Invoke` calls. I your case that would be:

```cs
app.WaitForElement (c => c.Button ("buttonGo")); 
app.Query(c => c.Button("buttonGo").Invoke("getBackground").Invoke("getColor"));
```

This will return the color id of the button.

Comment: Unfortunatley I get null returned on the Invoke("getBackground") not sure why

Comment: This doesn't work as you would need a cast to get to the `ColorDrawable` to invoke the `getColor`method.